# Function defined by parts is a random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am studying distribution functions of random variables. The text I'm reading has the next example: Suppose we toss a fair coin, and if it comes up $H$, then $X = 1,$ and if it comes up $T,$ then $X$ is determined by spinning a pointer and noting its final position on a scale from 0 to 2, that is, $X$ is then uniformly distributed over the interval [0,2].

Then proceeds to compute the distribution function utilizing Law of Total Probability.
I don't have any problem understanding the way in an intuitively fashion because conditioning under the result of head or tail we can utilizing 'geometric probability'.
My question is: Why $X$ defined in such manner is a random variable?

I am testing some ways to define $X$ as a function by parts, but I have trouble when I am utilizing the definition of inverse mapping of Borel sets or $\{X\leq x\}$ because I think is necesary utilize some random variable $Y$ with uniform distribution over $[0,2]$, but I cannot see how to define $X$ in terms of $Y.$ What is the proper way to define $X$ as function in such manner it be the random variable of the experiment?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: $X=Y+(1-Y)U$ where $Y$ is binomial with success probability $1/2$ and $U$ is uniform on $[0,2]$. Since measurability is stable under addition and multiplication, $X$ is a random variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AndrewZhang.  I agree with you, when $Y$ is Bernoulli(1/2). or Bin(1,1/2). My doubt is if $\omega\in\Omega =\{H,T\}$ is de sampling space, how is defined $U(\omega)?$ I can't see how the sampling space of the experiment is connected with $U.$

Comment: Usually the sample space is left as abstract. If you really want to construct one here, one way would be $\Omega = \{0,1\}\times [0,2]$ with the product $\sigma$ field $\mathcal F = 2^{\{0,1\}} \otimes \mathcal B([0,2])$ and $U,Y$ are the projection maps $Y(\omega) = \omega_1$ and $U(\omega) = \omega_2$. Take the product measure for your probability measure.

Comment: I thought that because of the coin toss determines the value of $X.$ But now is not clear to me what is the sampling space.

Comment: Oh you're right! Everything now has sense. Thanks for your help.